# K&R style function definition compile using g++

Tags: c++, c, kernighan-and-ritchie

When compiling a c file that uses old style function definition like

```
int foo(a)
   int a;
{
  ...
}
```

g++ will give and error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope.
gcc can parse this.
Is there a way to let g++ recognize this?

This comes up as an issue to me because I'm compiling a mix of c and c++ files. 
A related question is what's the standard practice 
of building this type of mixed source? Running g++ on all files or only the cc files? The former is convenient but keeps getting me some trouble because of the inconsistencies between c and c++ specification(for example, char[4]="four";)

Comment: Hey guys can you also suggest how to make g++ compile PHP as well???

Comment: Do you really still use code that was not touched since 1989?

Comment: @kay: There's actually tons of broken code still using K&R functions definitions. Most of it is in old BSD- or Sun-derived software; some old GNU software has it too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way to let `g++` recognize this?

This syntax is not supported in C++.

> Running `g++` on all files or only the cc files?

See e.g. [*Compiling C++ programs*](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html#Invoking-G_002b_002b) from the GCC docs:

> C++ source files conventionally use one of the suffixes .C', .cc, .cpp, .CPP, .c++, .cp, or .cxx; C++ header files often use .hh, .hpp, .H, or (for shared template code) .tcc; and preprocessed C++ files use the suffix .ii. GCC recognizes files with these names and compiles them as C++ programs even if you call the compiler the same way as for compiling C programs (usually with the name `gcc`).
>
> However, the use of `gcc` does not add the C++ library. `g++` is a program that calls GCC and treats .c, .h and .i files as C++ source files instead of C source files unless `-x` is used, and automatically specifies linking against the C++ library. This program is also useful when precompiling a C header file with a .h extension for use in C++ compilations.

So two possibilities:

1. Run `gcc` on C files, and `g++` on C++ files.
2. Run `gcc` on all files.

In both cases you will need to link with `g++` (or `gcc -lstdc++`).

Comment: To elaborate - if you are using a C++ compiler, you have to be compiling C++ code.  Not all C code is legal C++ code.

Comment: The difference in *almost no difference* is actually quite important. When compiling, the executable `g++` will force C++ language, while the executable `gcc` will decide the language based on the extension of the file (i.e. it can compile C and C++). When calling the linker. That is, the answer to the question is that if instead of always calling `g++` he should be calling `gcc` and modify the linker command.

Comment: It can't be stressed enough that **C code is not C++** and you **cannot compile it with a C++ compiler**. Even if compiling succeeds, that's no guarantee that the code will behave as expected; there are plenty of cases where the same code has different semantics in C versus C++. The only way it would be valid to compile C with a C++ compiler is if you know the code was written in the (very ugly) language that is the intersection of C and C++. Since OP is dealing with code containing K&R function definitions, it's definitely not in that class.

Answer (score 5):

Oli is correct: C++ doesn't support old-style function definitions.

Compile C with a C compiler (such as gcc).

Compile C++ with a C++ compiler (such as g++).

They're two different (though closely related) languages.  You can use C++'s `extern "C"` feature to invoke C code from C++ and vice versa; see section 32 of the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to compile both C and C++, you are better off compiling always with `gcc` (it will choose the language based on the file extension) than `g++` (will always compile as C++). You will need to change your linker options to include C++ standard library (and `-lm` if you use it) as those are automatically added by `g++` but not `gcc`.

Alternatively, a better option is to call the `g++` for C++ and `gcc` for C files. That should not be too hard to manage by configuring the build system.